# Alternative to ICANN?

Tags: dns, p2p

What are major DNS services offered that aren't state-controlled. Better yet, why can't we take Bitcoin's model and create a truly decentralized system with P2P DNS?

I see potential reasons behind P2P DNS:

- Logistical nightmare
- Endless domain registration
- Much like shift from ipv4 to ipv6

Comment: "Much like shift from IPv4 to IPv6": do you mean it as "nice on paper, does not happen in the real world" ?

Comment: So, you and I walk up to a third person, each of us with another guy with us and say, "This guy here is Jeff Bezos".  And they're both bald, and promise drone delivery, etc.  How does guy number 3 know which "Jeff" is the real one - or even if _either_ is the "Amazon.com Jeff"?  Why should person 3 listen to either of us?  If 3 gives one of the Jeffs $10 and doesn't receive a book, what name/address does he give the police?  How can 3 be confident that a new Jeff is the "correct" one?

Comment: http://dotp2p.io/

Answer (score 2):

You can do it if you want to. Go ahead. No? Why haven't you switched yet?

Yep, there's the problem. Nobody else switched. If you change the rules, you're effectively creating a *different* Internet. One that isn't entirely compatible with the Internet we all have, which means nobody is on it but you.

This Internet, the one we're using right now, works well enough. There's stuff we don't like, but altogether it works well enough that nobody wants to start over.

If you want to change some rule, like DNS or routing or some other core component, chances are there's a few people on the fringes of society who will play along. So set up your Alternate DNS Root and talk to them. Five dollars says I know what they'll want to talk about.